# Showing MON and CAT are equivalent categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid

I am struggling with an equivalence of categories.
Let $\mathbf{Mon}$ be the category of monoids, and let $\mathbf{Cat}$ be the category whose objects are all categories with exactly one object. The morphisms from object $A$ to $B$ in $\mathbf{Cat}$ are all functors from $A$ to $B.$ I want to show that $\mathbf{Mon}$ and $\mathbf{Cat}$ are equivalent categories. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see how a monoid is a category with only one element?

Comment: yes. take a monoid and identity map

Comment: I can construct 1 natural functor from MON to CAT, but I cannot construct the inverse

Comment: If CAT is the category of locally small categories with only one element, then define a monoid from an object of CAT by letting the Hom-set be the elements and the binary product the composition.

Comment: Mon and Cat are isomorphic or just equivalent?

Comment: They are clearly isomorphic.

Comment: @magma: At the "clearly" level, I think you only get an equivalence. You only get a "clear" isomorphism if you fix a specific object to be used (alternatively, if your universe has a strictly unique singleton). I think you can arrange for an isomorphism in NBG by doing some chicanery with the axiom of limitation of size, since each isomorphism class in the two categories is proper. (maybe you can get away with less?)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Am I missing something obvious, or are you just fixing the object that all of the one-object categories are using?

Comment: As an aside, I generally hate contemplating *isomorphism* of categories, since there are all sorts of basic things we're trained to gloss over that can affect things. For example, the definition of a group involves a product. Do we fix a specific product functor ahead of time or allow each group to pick its own choice of product? This is a point we habitually ignore, but the two choices would give nonisomorphic definitions of **Grp** (but they would be equivalent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A monoid $(M,*,1)$ can be seen as a category with only one object $\bullet$, the same way a group is a groupoid with a single object. The composition of morphisms corresponds to the multiplication $"*"$ of elements and the rule $f\circ(g∘h)=(f∘g)∘h$ means that multiplication is associative, while the single identity arrow $1_\bullet$ is the unit of $*$ since $1∘f=f∘1=f$ for any $f\in M$.

A functor $F:M\to N$ between two categories with a single object is uniquely determined by its arrow function, and since there is only one hom-set, any function is allowed, as long as it respect the composition of arrows and the identity, i.e. $F(1_∙)=1_∙$ and $F(g∘f)=F(g)∘F(f)$. But these are just the properties that we require from a homomorphism between monoids. Hence, a functor between two monoids, considered as categories with a single object, is basically the same as a homomorphism, and vice versa.

Comment: @stefen. Can you explain a little bit more. I am very confused

Comment: @abc: This shows that **Cat** and **Mon** are basically the same. A category with a single object is a monoid, and a functor between such categories is a homomorphism between the monoids.