# A full list of the main properties of the $1$-category $\mathbf{Cat}$

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

The category $\mathbf{Cat}$ agrees with the category of small categories and functors. See it as a $1$-category. It is possible to show for instance that it is bicomplete but not regular (why it is not regular? Where can I find a detailed proof?)  Actually, it is quite difficult to find a full list of properties satisfied by $\mathbf{Cat}$. Is there some book or paper where such a category has been fully investigated? I'm interested for instance in extremality, regularity, effectiveness, strongness of monics and epics, stability of epics under pullbacks, effectiveness of equivalence relations and so on. If possible, can you provide a full list of properties of the $1$-category $\mathbf{Cat}$ (with reference)?

Moreover, it is possible to show that it is equivalent to the category $\mathbf{Mon}$ of monoids. Furthermore, in his book, Spivak showed that such a category is equivalent to the category of Schemas (it is a definition taken from database theory) Are there other categories that have been proved to be equivalent (or isomorphic) to $\mathbf{Cat}$?

Comment: Usually people are more interested in $\mathbf{Cat}$ as a 2-category rather than a 1-category (considering it as a 1-category roughly means you are doing abstract algebra with categories as your objects, rather than studying category theory).  Also, $\mathbf{Cat}$ cannot be equivalent to $\mathbf{Mon}$ since $\mathbf{Mon}$ has a zero object and $\mathbf{Cat}$ does not.

Comment: I would start with the observation that it is locally finitely presentable and derive some properties from that.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Unless you study Cat as a model category, in which case the 1-categorical properties, such as being cartesian closed and locally finitely presentable are suddenly very useful.  If you don't have the axiom of choice, this is in fact preferable to studying Cat as a 2-category, unless you use anafunctors.  But developing anafunctors requires 1-categorical properties as well.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey So, this answer is wrong: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556095/showing-mon-and-cat-are-equivalent-categories?rq=1

Comment: @TheWanderer: No, it is not wrong because Cat is not equivalent to its full subcategory consisting of categories with a single object.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry for my distraction. Well, reading something online I found, as in the above comments, that $\mathbf{Cat}$ is locally finitely presentable and cartesian closed. Well, are there other properties, as those I listed in my question? Have these properties been already studied?